# Keeping IClientValidatable outside the model layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, custom-attributes, separation-of-concerns

I'm using **Data Annotations** to validate my model classes. I wrote a couple of custom attributes as well. Ultimately, the model is pushed to a web interface built in ASP.NET MVC, but I want to keep a clean separation of concerns, so the model classes has its own assembly (which will also be used by console apps). Having to use the `IClientValidatable` interface (which is a web concern) in the model layer breaks the loose coupling I'm aiming for. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: After so many hours of researching a RequiredIf custom annotation with client-side validation, it seems you're the only one that thought to keep the client portion separate from the domain!  (thanks for asking, saved me the trouble)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add adapter for data annotation attribute.

For example you have MyValidationAttribute.

You need add adapter like following:

```
 public class MyValidationAttributeAdapter  : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<MyValidationAttribute>
    {
        public MyValidationAttributeAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, MyValidationAttribute attribute) : base(metadata, context, attribute)
        {
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
        {
            //return client rule here
            return base.GetClientValidationRules();
        }
    }
```

And somewhere on application start add code, which register this adapter:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(MyValidationAttribute), typeof(MyValidationAttributeAdapter));
```