# ASP.net core MVC 6 Data Annotations separation of concerns

Tags: data-annotations, asp.net-core-mvc

I want put the Data Annotations Attribute and the `IClientValidatable` interface in two seperate assemblies to have separation of concerns. One is called Common and the other Comman.Web.

These links explain how it works in MVC 5:

[Keeping IClientValidatable outside the model layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639752/keeping-iclientvalidatable-outside-the-model-layer)

http://www.eidias.com/blog/2012/5/25/mvc-custom-validator-with-client-side-validation

Unfortunately in MVC 6 there is no

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
    typeof(MyValidationAttribute), 
    typeof(MyValidationAttributeAdapter)
);
```

How does it work in ASP.net core MVC 6? I use the RC1.

Answer (score 2):

In `Startup.cs`, in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.ModelValidatorProviders.Insert(0, new CustomModelValidatorProvider());
});
```

You have to adjust your code as the ASP.NET Core 1.0 API is changed. You could find a sample implementation in the asp.net repo: [DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/144766f2e3ee802f50e143ee29d5ad654333a171/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations/Internal/DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.cs)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
In your example, you use a `IModelValidatorProvider`. But I wanna regist a `IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider` like here:
[ValidationAttributeAdapterProvider.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/144766f2e3ee802f50e143ee29d5ad654333a171/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations/Internal/ValidationAttributeAdapterProvider.cs).

Comment: Is where any ideas in ASP.net core RC2?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.net core 1.0 I was able to do this by replacing the IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider service.

```
public class CustomValidationAttributeAdapterProvider : IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider
{
    public IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider internalImpl;

    public CustomValidationAttributeAdapterProvider()
    {
        internalImpl = new ValidationAttributeAdapterProvider();
    }

    public IAttributeAdapter GetAttributeAdapter(ValidationAttribute attribute, IStringLocalizer stringLocalizer)
    {
        IAttributeAdapter adapter = internalImpl.GetAttributeAdapter(attribute, stringLocalizer);

        if (adapter == null)
        {
            var type = attribute.GetType();

            if (type == typeof(CustomValidatorAttribute))
            {
                adapter = new CustomNumberValidatorAdapter((CustomValidatorAttribute)attribute, stringLocalizer);
            }
        }

        return adapter;
    }
}
```

In Startup ConfigureServices

```
if (services.Any(f => f.ServiceType == typeof(IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider)))
{
    services.Remove(services.Single(f => f.ServiceType == typeof(IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider)));
}
services.AddScoped<IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider, CustomValidationAttributeAdapterProvider>();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That works.
Do you know what is the `IModelValidatorProvider` for?

Comment: I first looked at IModelValidatorProvider but i'm not sure how it works. I was able to register my own IModelValidatorProvider implementation, but whenever CreateValidators was called, there would be no ValidatorItems so I really couldn't do anything with it.