# DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

In ASP.Net MVC 5, custom data annotation validator can be implemented by inheriting **DataAnnotationsModelValidator**  and registering using **DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(...)**. In ASP.Net Core MVC, how can I achieve this?

I found similar question at [ASP.net core MVC 6 Data Annotations separation of concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36692627/asp-net-core-mvc-6-data-annotations-separation-of-concerns), but can anyone show me simple example code?

Answer (score 16):

It seems to me ASP.NET Core MVC does not have support for  `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter` anymore. The solution I discovered is as follows:

Suppose I want to change the Validator for `RequiredAttribute` to my own validator adaptor (`MyRequiredAttributeAdaptor`), Change the default error message of `EmailAddressAttribute`, and change the Localized Error Message Source for 'CompareAttribute' to my own message.

**1- Create a custom ValidationAttributeAdapterProvider**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations.Internal;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class CustomValidationAttributeAdapterProvider
    : ValidationAttributeAdapterProvider, IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider
{
    public CustomValidationAttributeAdapterProvider() { }

    IAttributeAdapter IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider.GetAttributeAdapter(
        ValidationAttribute attribute,
        IStringLocalizer stringLocalizer)
    {
        IAttributeAdapter adapter;
        if (attribute is RequiredAttribute)
        {
            adapter = new MyRequiredAttributeAdaptor((RequiredAttribute) attribute, stringLocalizer);
        }
        else if (attribute is EmailAddressAttribute)
        {
            attribute.ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address.";
            adapter = base.GetAttributeAdapter(attribute, stringLocalizer);
        }
        else if (attribute is CompareAttribute)
        {
            attribute.ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidCompare"; 
            attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ValidationMessages);
            var theNewattribute = attribute as CompareAttribute;
            adapter = new CompareAttributeAdapter(theNewattribute, stringLocalizer);
        }
        else
        {
            adapter = base.GetAttributeAdapter(attribute, stringLocalizer);
        }

        return adapter;
    }
}
```

**2- Add the CustomValidationAttributeAdapterProvider to start up:**

Add the following line to `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` in Startup.cs:

```cs
services.AddSingleton <IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider, CustomValidationAttributeAdapterProvider> ();
```

**Here is MyRequiredAttributeAdaptor adaptor:**

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations.Internal;

public class MyRequiredAttributeAdaptor : AttributeAdapterBase<RequiredAttribute>
{
    public MyRequiredAttributeAdaptor(RequiredAttribute attribute, IStringLocalizer stringLocalizer)
        : base(attribute, stringLocalizer)
    {
    }

    public override void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-required", GetErrorMessage(context));
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override string GetErrorMessage(ModelValidationContextBase validationContext)
    {
        if (validationContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(validationContext));
        }

        return GetErrorMessage(validationContext.ModelMetadata, validationContext.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName());
    }
}
```

**References:**

1- See the example of Microsoft: Entropy project: This is a great sample for diffrent features of .NET Core. In this question: see the `MinLengthSixAttribute` implementation in the Mvc.LocalizationSample.Web sample:

[https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Mvc.LocalizationSample.Web](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/master/samples/Mvc.LocalizationSample.Web)

2- In order to see how the attribute adapters works see asp.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations on github:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations

Answer (score -2):

To define a custom validator by a annotation you can define your own class that derives from `ValidationAttribute` and override the `IsValid` method. There is no need to register this class explicitly.

In this example a custom validation attribute is used to accept only odd numbers as valid values.

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    [OddNumber]
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class OddNumberAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var number = (int) value;
            if (number % 2 == 1)
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            else
                return new ValidationResult("Only odd numbers are valid.");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Not a number.");
        }            
    }
}
```

A second approach is that the Model class implements `IValidatableObject`. This is especially useful, if validation requires access to multiple members of the model class. Here is the second version of the odd number validator:

```cs
public class MyModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Number % 2 == 0)
            yield return new ValidationResult(
                 "Only odd numbers are valid.", 
                 new [] {"Number"});
    }
}
```

You can find more information about custom validation in https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/validation.html#custom-validation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I want to use both server-side and client-side validations, and also separation of concern logic, for this purpose, I created -     `public class RequiredIfValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute { // ... }`, and `public class RequiredIfValidationAdaptor : AttributeAdapterBase<RequiredIfValidationAttribute> { // ...}, `but I don't know idea how to register that adapter in **ASP.Net Core MVC**. In MVC 5, I used **DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(...)**. Do you have any more idea?